# Placing double line conference name in the header in IEEEtran class

Tags: ieeetran, eso-pic

I have been trying to add a conference name in the header of IEEEtran class. I have been following [this](https://shantoroy.com/latex/add-copyright-conference-name/) format. It works fine for single line conference name. When the conference name is 2 line long, the second line become **right aligned**. I want to make it left aligned.

MWE is given below

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}


%------Conference Name-------%
\newcommand\AtPageUpperMyright[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{0.0\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{-1cm}){%
            \parbox{.96\textwidth}{\raggedleft\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont #1}}%
}}%
\newcommand{\conf}[1]{%
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
        \AtPageUpperMyright{#1}
    }
}


\begin{document}    
\title{A random xyz manuscript}
\maketitle

        %------conference Name-------%
\conf{2021 5th International Conference on Electrical Engineering and Information \& Communication Technology (ICEEICT)\\ 
    Military Institute of Science and Technology (MIST), Dhaka-1216, Bangladesh}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2-3].
\end{abstract}

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

    \subsection{Subsection A}
    ........
    
\end{document}
```

Can anyone explain this part of the code - how it becomes right aligned

```
\newcommand\AtPageUpperMyright[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{0.0\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{-1cm}){%
            \parbox{.96\textwidth}{\raggedleft\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont #1}}%
```

Comment: *Both* lines are right-aligned, because of the command `\raggedleft`. If you want alignment to the right, replace `\raggedleft` with `\raggedright`. Oh, and I would also replace `0.0\paperwidth` with, e.g., `0.01\paperwidth`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks a lot. I thought \raggedleft means left-aligned. I am still facing a problem. I changed .96\textwidth with \textwidth and .0\paperwidth with .05\paperwidth. It's kind of ok now. But I want the line start from the margin not from the edge of the page, I can adjust that by increasing \paperwidth., but it's not the actual way. how can I get the conference name start from the margin not from the edge of the page. Please write as answer, I will accept.

Comment: And what would that problem be? (Sadly, my mind-reading skills are worthless.)

Comment: Please see the previous comment @Mico. I have edited that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So why not just insert a `\parbox` into the header?  `\headheight` is big enough for two lines.

BTW, it just looked weird without `\centering`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\conf}[1]{%
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{% default title page headers, no footers
\def\@oddhead{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd\headerbox-\columnsep}{\centering \@IEEEheaderstyle #1}}%
\let\@evenhead\@empty
\def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}% 
\let\@evenfoot\@empty}}
\newcommand{\mycopyrightnotice}{\footnotesize 978-0-7381-1102-5/20/\$31.00 $\copyright$ 2021 IEEE\hfill}
\makeatother

%------conference Name-------%
\conf{2021 5th International Conference on Electrical Engineering and Information \& Communication Technology (ICEEICT)\\ 
    Military Institute of Science and Technology (MIST), Dhaka-1216, Bangladesh}

\begin{document}    
\title{A random xyz manuscript}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2-3].
\end{abstract}

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

    \subsection{Subsection A}
    ........
    
\end{document}
```

---

If the conference has a logo, you could use that to balance the lopsidedness.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%------Conference Header-------%
\newsavebox\headerbox
\savebox\headerbox{\includegraphics[height=\headheight]{example-image}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\conf}[1]{%
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{% default title page headers, no footers
\def\@oddhead{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd\headerbox-\columnsep}{\@IEEEheaderstyle #1}\hfill{\usebox\headerbox}}\relax
\let\@evenhead\@empty
\def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}% 
\let\@evenfoot\@empty}}
\newcommand{\mycopyrightnotice}{\footnotesize 978-0-7381-1102-5/20/\$31.00 $\copyright$ 2021 IEEE\hfill}
\makeatother

%------conference Name-------%
\conf{2021 5th International Conference on Electrical Engineering and Information \& Communication Technology (ICEEICT)\\ 
    Military Institute of Science and Technology (MIST), Dhaka-1216, Bangladesh}

\begin{document}    
\title{A random xyz manuscript}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2-3].
\end{abstract}

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

    \subsection{Subsection A}
    ........
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, It works perfelty fine

Comment: But my copyright notice isn't working now. its in the footer

Comment: I didn't see a copyright notice in the MWE, but you can add it using \def\@oddfoot{...}.

Comment: \makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
 \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
 \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
 {\footnotesize 978-0-7381-1102-5/20/\$31.00 $\copyright$2021 IEEE\hfill}% <--- Change here
 \gdef\mycopyrightnotice{}% just in case
}

Comment: This is the copy right notice. But its not working. I haven't mentioned it with this question because I thought it was not relevent

Comment: There can be only one `\def\ps@IEEEtitlepage`

Comment: How to fix this? anyway

Comment: I've been editing the answer.